# Data Retention for Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to know if there is a maximum data retention period for data stored in a Blob Storage?
What I'm trying to know is if I store something in a Blob Storage, are there any risks that this data will be deleted by Microsoft after a certain period of time?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage is *durable*: Unless you delete an object (or storage account), or cancel your subscription, your data persists.

Data can also be deleted if you've configured a data lifecycle policy (e.g. delete blobs older than a specified number of days).

Comment: David is right, there is no data retention for Azure Storage unless you create a life cycle management policy explicitly.

Comment: Does it mean that if I do nothing and keep my subscription up and running, I will have my data forever? Even if for example I never access it? No chances to lose it?

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER - there is documentation that goes into quite a bit of detail on how Azure Storage is architected, that you should consider studying, if you have concerns about this. There's also docs around geo-replication that you might want to read, for for disaster recovery (it's an option for storage), to deal with things like natural disasters. But other than that... I'm not sure what else to provide in my answer. As I (and @Zhaoxing) stated already, it stays until you delete it, it expires, or you close your subscription.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon. I have a question from a customer that asked me if I'm very sure that it will never be deleted, it is why I'm asking.